# Create <select> from list - indent child items?

Tags: jquery, list, select, html-lists

I have a UL LI menu that I am turning into a select dropdown when you're viewing it on a mobile.

I want to now indent child items e.g

- List item 1
- -- Child item 1
- ---- Child Child item 1
- -- Child item 2
- List item 2

Rather than listing in one single line.

I'm happy to just add nbsp to keep things easy - or add classes and CSS if more suitable.

The code I am currently using to generate the select is:

```
$("<select />").appendTo("#primary-nav");

  $("<option />", {
     "selected": "selected",
     "value"   : "",
     "text"    : "Go to..."
  }).appendTo("#primary-nav select");

  $("#primary-nav a").each(function() {
   var el = $(this);
   $("<option />", {
       "value"   : el.attr("href"),
       "text"    : el.text()
   }).appendTo("#primary-nav select");
  });

  $("#primary-nav select").change(function() {
    window.location = $(this).find("option:selected").val();
  });
```

The menu it is generating from is built like:

```
<ul>
  <li><a>Item 1</a>
      <ul>
          <li><a>Child Item 1</a>
              <ul>
                  <li><a>Child Item 1</a></li>
              </ul>
          </li>
          <li><a>Child Item 2</a></li>
      </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a>Item 2</a></li>
</ul>
```

Here is a fiddle with an example: http://jsfiddle.net/C5S32/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do what you want, and it's pretty customizable. http://jsfiddle.net/C5S32/7/

```
var options = '<option selected>Go to...</option>';
$('#primary-nav').find('a').each(function () {
    var text = $(this).text(),
        depth = $(this).parent().parents('ul').length,
        depthChar = '',
        i = 1;
    for (i; i < depth; i++) { depthChar += '&ndash;&nbsp;'; }
    options += '<option>' + depthChar + text + '</option>';
});
$('<select />').append(options).appendTo('#primary-nav');
```

As a side note, in your code you're appending stuff many times. It's better to append everything in one call to avoid excessive reflows.

Comment: This seems to be a cleaner approach than mine. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

This should do it, Not sure about support for "margin-left" on mobiles but will point you in the right direction.

http://jsfiddle.net/C5S32/2/

EDIT: Seems only Firefox allows margin on option elements,

http://jsfiddle.net/C5S32/6/

Comment: This does what I needed so I've voted it up. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

See if this suits your needs:

http://jsfiddle.net/C5S32/1/

I just added this:

```
li {
    padding-left: 1em;
}​
```

Comment: I somehow think Justin wants to have the select options indented. Not the li?

Comment: Yeah I need the select options indented not the LI :)

Answer (score 0):

Best Solution that I found adds child indented "-" marks automatically. Make sure that you change the top ".navbar .nav" to your own div class or id that is setup on the original ul.

http://snipplr.com/view/66721/