# Create automatic Links from Select List

Tags: javascript, html, select

I have a simple `<select>` list which I receive via an external API, which can not be changed.

My problem is the following: I want to convert this `<select>` list into a bunch of regular html links. I want to style the list using CSS in ways which do not work on `<select>`. I hide the original list with 'display:none'

This:

```
<select style="display:none;">
  <option value="E1">Entry 1</option>
  <option value="E2">Entry 2</option>
  <option value="E3">Entry 3</option>
</select>
```

Should be converted into:

```
<a href="E1" class="X1">Entry 1</a>
<a href="E2" class="X2">Entry 2</a>
<a href="E3" class="X3">Entry 3</a>
```

How do I achieve this?

I have found an Solution, but it's the wrong way! [Create <select> from list - indent child items?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9358148/create-select-from-list-indent-child-items)

Comment: Much better now. It is acceptable to answer ones own question, but you should use the answer field for this purpose instead of editing your question.

Comment: Please do add a self-answer.  This could be helpful to others in the future.  Don't forget to accept it too.

Comment: You will even receive a [badge](http://stackoverflow.com/badges/14/self-learner) if others like your answer.

Comment: Thanks so much for all the great help, I have answered the Question now! I think this is better! Stackoverflow rocks ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution, it can be tested at http://jsfiddle.net/C5S32/44/

```
var options = '';
$('select').find('option').each(function () {
    var
    val = $(this).val(),
    text = $(this).text(),
    i = 1;
    options += '<a href="' + val + '">' + text + '</a>';
});
$('<div class="test" />').append(options).appendTo('#selectnav');
```